# how to works on insert,update data from a table using store Procedure

Tags: mysql, swing

if i use one table in two different Stored procedure name, (one for insert , one for update command) it showing syntax error.

first i created studentrc SP:

```
delimiter //
create procedure studentrc(in student_name varchar(20),in Reg_no int(6),in mark1 int(3), in mark2 int(3),in total int(10))
begin
insert into studentrecords values(student_name,Reg_no,mark1,mark2,total);
end; //
```

no errors

next i create studentrcs SP:

```
delimiter //
create procedure studentrcs(inout Reg_no int(6))
begin
UPDATE studentrecords
set student_name=?,mark1=?,mark2=?,total=?
where Reg_no=?;
end;//
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE studentrecords
set student_name=?,mark1=?,mark2=?,total=?
where Reg_no=' at line 3

how can rectify this error...

Answer (score 0):

I'll be the first to admit I'm not a SQL guru by any means, but shouldn't you be taking in more variables and using them in place of the question marks?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the news values in the args list

```
 create procedure studentrcs(sname varchar(100),m1 varchar(100),m2 varchar(100),total int,inout Reg_noarg int(6))
 begin
 UPDATE studentrecords
 set student_name=sname ,mark1=m1,mark2=m2,total=totalarg
 where Reg_no=Reg_noarg ;
```

Answer (score 0):

for "INSERT"

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `mydatabase`.`myprocedurename` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `myprocedurename`(IN field1 VARCHAR(50),
IN field2 INT(10),IN field3 INT(10), IN field4 VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO mytablename (FIELD_1,FIELD_2,FIELD_3,FIELD_4) VALUES 
(field1,field2,field3,field4);
END $$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

size which i have given in IN parameter should be equal to field size in table

for "UPDATE"

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `mydatabase`.`myprocedurename` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `myprocedurename`(IN field1 VARCHAR(50),
IN field2 INT(10) )
BEGIN
UPDATE mytablename  SET FIELD_1=filed1 WHERE  FIELD_2=field2;
END $$
```

size which i have given in IN parameter should be equal to field size in table

hope this may help you.